# Cannot update contactusgin People api using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I´m trying to update existing contact using People service from Google apps gs. I have a contact like this:

```
let contactInfo = {
  "name" : "Jhon",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "phone": "+1999999",
  "rn": "people/c8289118840931811524",
  "etag": "%EgkBAj0JPgs/Ny4aBAECBQciDDV1TzVFdXY0ckhnPQ=="
}
```

I created the folowing function in order to update contact more easily:

```
function updateContact(contactInfo){
  //var updatePersonFields = "updatePersonFields=names,phoneNumbers,emailAddresses";
  var bodyRequest = {
    "resourceName": contactInfo.rn,
    "etag": contactInfo.etag,
    "names": [{
      "givenName": contactInfo.name,
      "familyName": contactInfo.lastName,
    }],
    "phoneNumbers": [{
      'value': contactInfo.phone
    }],
    "emailAddresses": [{
      'value': contactInfo.email
    }]
  };

  People.People.updateContact(bodyRequest, contactInfo.rn);
}
```

However, the document guide for updateContact needs 3 parameters: Path parameters, Query Parameters and request body:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact

In order to update contact, I have to pass updatePersonfields, but it is a Query Parameter and the updateContact just only receive 2 parameters.

I know that etag and updatePersonfields is needed, as the link explain it:
https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts?hl=en#update_an_existing_contact

How can I add the Query Parameter updatePersonFields (in comments)?

If updatePersonField is not send it, I have the following error:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.people.updateContact failed with error:
updatePersonFields mask is required. Please specify one or more valid paths.
Valid paths are documented at
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact.
```

Thanks you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, please include `updatePersonFields` to 3rd argument of `People.People.updateContact` as an object.

In this case, when you use People API of Advanced Google services with the script editor of Google Apps Script, you can see the document of `updateContact(resource: Peopleapi_v1.Peopleapi.V1.Schema.Person, resourceName: string, optionalArgs: Object)` by the auto-completion of script editor.

So, when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
People.People.updateContact(bodyRequest, contactInfo.rn);
```

#### To:

```
People.People.updateContact(bodyRequest, contactInfo.rn, {updatePersonFields: "emailAddresses,names,phoneNumbers"});
```

#### Note:

- When your `bodyRequest` is invalid value, an error occurs. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: people.updateContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact)

Comment: Inside the paremeter with the shorcuts CTRL+SHIF+SPACE I can see the two overloaded methods. thanks.