# App script to Search the resourceName from a person by using the unstructuredName in a Cell in a Google Sheet and placing it a Cell of the same sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-people-api

I have a google sheet ("Test") where column 2 (B) contains the names of the contactpersons from my Google Contacts. I want to place in column 1 (A) the resourceName of the contactperson.

The Cell in Column 1 (A) contains no data. (There has the result to be placed after running the function)
The Cell in Column 2 (B) contains in row 2 the name "Mark Gerrits".
In GoogleContacts "Mark Gerrits " has the "person/cxxxxxxxx" as the resourceName (actually: "people/cxxxxxxxx")

What i want to achieve is that by using the People.searchContact method [Method: people.searchContacts](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts), in Cell A2 the resourceName of "Mark Gerrits" is placed.
These are the steps

- open an inputbox where i fill in the rownumber corresponding with the row of the contactperson for which i want to find the resourceName (ic: row 2)
- search - with the method People.SearchContacts - in the Google Contact the person with the name in cell (rownumber, 2) > "Mark Gerrits"
- finds the corresponding resourceName of that person (ic: )
- places the found resourceName in the same row - rownumber - but the first column (column 1 or A): "people/cxxxxxxxx

I used the function from this entry [Format for Google People API searchContacts()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202812/format-for-google-people-api-searchcontacts)

Many Thanks to HotDogWater and Oz Ben-David !

I modified and tested this function over and over again.

What I was expecting is that the resourceName of the person corresponding with his unstrucuredName (the information provided in the google sheet)  would be placed in the google sheet.

Sometimes the function worked and put the found resourceName in the cell, sometimes it gives no resourceName at all (of course i checked if the person exitsts!)

```
function getResourceNameFromCellValue() {
//see documented: function getNameFromEmail()
var spreadsheetId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
// Open spreadsheet with the ID
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
// Name of the sheet
var dataSheetName = "Test";
// Get the sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(dataSheetName);

//var numberRow = 2;
var rowNumber = Browser.inputBox("Bepaal rijnummer van Contactpersoon", "Voer het nummer van de rij in:", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
// Give the rownumber in the sheet for which Contact you want the resourceName

var rowAsNumber = Number(rowNumber);
var NameColumn = 2; 
var Name = sheet.getRange(rowAsNumber,NameColumn).getValue();
Name = Name.toString();
//var name = Name;
var resourceName = Name;
var response;

Browser.msgBox('Succes','The resourceName of the Person with unstructuredName "' + Name + '" is placed in the Cell.',Browser.Buttons.OK);

  People.People.searchContacts({ //Empty the cache
    query: '',
    readMask: 'names,emailAddresses',
  });

  response = People.People.searchContacts({
    query: Name,
    readMask: 'names,emailAddresses'
  });

  // Check if the response contains contacts
  if (response.results && response.results.length > 0) {
    //name = response.results[0].person.names[0].displayName;
    resourceName = response.results[0].person.resourceName;
    
  } else {
    People.OtherContacts.search({ //Clear the cache
      query: '',
      readMask: 'names,emailAddresses',
    });

    response = People.OtherContacts.search({
      query: Name,
      readMask: 'names,emailAddresses'
    });

    // Check if the response contains contacts
    if (response.results && response.results.length > 0) {
      // name = response.results[0].person.names[0].displayName;
      resourceName = response.results[0].person.resourceName;
    }
  }


//Logger.log(name);
Logger.log(response.results[0].person.resourceName);
Logger.log(resourceName);

// put the value of the result (name) in cell
//sheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue(name);
//sheet.getRange(rowAsNumber, NameColumn).setValue(resourceName);
sheet.getRange(rowAsNumber,2);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the string in your spreadsheet exactly matches the name in your contacts,  no extra spaces, no captialization, no extra characters, no typographical differences?

Comment: Where in the Google Sheet would you like the `resourceName` to be placed specifically? Also, could you share a sample data and an expected behavior for a clearer goal you want to achieve?

Comment: @TheWizKid: in my code i use Name = Name.toString(); to make certain the string for the person to search for in the Google Contacts matches . Examples: (in my GoogleSheet) "mr. drs. Adriaan van Stoffelen" / in Google Contacts: "mr. drs. Adriaan van Stoffelen" The same for "Mark Gerrits" and "Mark Gerrits". I can't use (search)string FamliyName for getting the resourceName because - as i have many members in my family with the same lat name ("Gerrits")

Comment: @SputnikDrum2 is this the info you need? 
I have the Name in column B. 
That Name is used as a string to search for the resourceName.  
And - after executing the function, the resourceName of that person has to be placed in column A (in same row as where the Name of the person is placed)