# Google Apps Script - People API - How to update a contact (add them to a new contactGroup)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I want to take a spreadsheet of e-mails names and either A) add them as new contacts or B) update existing contacts to a specific Group/Label in my contacts list. I got the "add" part down, and I'm able to retrieve things like the Person ID and such. But for updating people already existing in my contacts, I'm getting stuck.

I have a simple function (based on Google's documentation) to update a contact by Person ID and Label/Group ID. Whenever I execute it, it throws this error:

`Exception: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only`

I've tried to follow the Google People API documentation, but it's a bit difficult for me since the examples are in JavaScript and I'm trying to use this in an Apps Script (and I'm no pro at either).

My main code is below for reference, where `personID` is a string that follows the *people/IDNUMBER* format, and `groupLabel` is a string in the *contactGroups/GROUPIDNUMBER* format:

```
function addContactToGroup(personID, groupLabel) {
    Logger.log("Updating: " + personID + " --> " + groupLabel);
    return People.People.updateContact({
      "resourceName": personID,
      "personFields": "memberships",
      "updatePersonFields": "memberships",
      "resource": {
        "memberships": [
          {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
              "contactGroupResourceName": groupLabel
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    });
}
```

**EDITED CODE:**

Answering my own question (sort of) because I did a bit of digging and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983088/cannot-update-contactusgin-people-api-using-google-apps-script).

But now I'm having issues with "etag." Is there a specific way I can get the etag to pass into the function? My updated (semi-working) code is:

```
function modifyContact(person, label) {
    Logger.log("Updating: " + person + " --> " + label);
    return People.People.updateContact({
        "resourceName": person,
        "etag": etag,
        "memberships": [
            {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
            "contactGroupResourceName": label
            }
          }
        ]
    },
        person,
        {updatePersonFields: "memberships"});
}
```

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. From your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to work your function `modifyContact` using the valid value of `etag`.

In this case, how about retrieving `etag` using [Method: people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function modifyContact(person, label) {
  const { etag } = People.People.get(person, { personFields: "memberships" });
  return People.People.updateContact({
    "resourceName": person,
    "etag": etag,
    "memberships": [
      {
        "contactGroupMembership": {
          "contactGroupResourceName": label
        }
      }
    ]
  },
    person,
    { updatePersonFields: "memberships" });
}
```

- When this script is run with the valid values of `person, label`, the label of `person` is changed to `label`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your values of `person, label` are valid values, and also, you have permission for updating it. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find the solution for etag using the people.get method. I structured my code differently from yours but I was able to use the get method to make it work. I tested it and my function updated the contact successfully!

Now my only other difficulty is that it **overwrote** the existing label on the contact. I can't find any way to simply **add* the new label, vs. overwriting any existing label(s) with the new one.

Would you suggest that I first retrieve the existing labels with the people.get method, and then pass the existing + new labels to people.updateContact?

Comment: @Corinne Jacobo Thank you for replying. From `Thank you! I was able to find the solution for etag using the people.get method. I structured my code differently from yours but I was able to use the get method to make it work. I tested it and my function updated the contact successfully!`, I understood that your question was resolved.

Comment: @Corinne Jacobo About your new question of `Now my only other difficulty is that it overwrote the existing label on the contact. I can't find any way to simply *add the new label, vs. overwriting any existing label(s) with the new one. Would you suggest that I first retrieve the existing labels with the people.get method, and then pass the existing + new labels to people.updateContact?`, I would like to support you.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I'll ask a new question regarding this specific issue.

Comment: @Corinne Jacobo Thank you for your response. When you post a new question, I would like to check it.