# Google Apps Script - People API - How to add contact to a Group/Label WITHOUT overwriting existing labels?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I asked another question about this particular piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76808296/google-apps-script-people-api-how-to-update-a-contact-add-them-to-a-new-con/76808676?noredirect=1#comment135409104_76808676), but I was able to resolve that issue thanks to the help I got on that thread.

```
function modifyContact(person, label, etag) {
    Logger.log("Updating: " + person + " --> " + label);
    return People.People.updateContact({
        "resourceName": person,
        "etag": etag,
        "memberships": [
            {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
            "contactGroupResourceName": label
            }
          }
        ]
    },
        person,
        {updatePersonFields: "memberships"});
}
```

Now that the code is fully functional, I'm wondering if there's any way to update the contact by simply **adding** a label, rather than **overwriting** all existing labels on the contact.

If there's no easy way to do this, I'm thinking that the best alternative would be to retrieve the existing labels using `people.get()` (which is how I'm retrieving all other information about the person) and then pass ALL labels into `people.updateContact()` so that the old and new labels, combined, will overwrite the new labels.

For example, if the contact has an existing `labelA`, after retrieving A and defining `labelB`, I would simply pass them both in under "memberships" when I update the contact, so that it overwrites the memberships but retains both labels.

```
"memberships": [
        {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
                "contactGroupResourceName": labelA
            }
        },
                {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
                "contactGroupResourceName": labelB
            }
        }
```

Is this the best way to do this? Or is there a better/more preferred way of updating without overwriting existing labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about modifying as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function modifyContact(person, label) {
  const { etag, memberships } = People.People.get(person, { personFields: "memberships" });
  return People.People.updateContact({
    "resourceName": person,
    "etag": etag,
    "memberships": [
      ...memberships, // Here, the existing labels are included.
      { "contactGroupMembership": { "contactGroupResourceName": label } }
    ]
  },
    person,
    { updatePersonFields: "memberships" });
}
```

- By this modification, `label` is added to the contact.

Comment: I think I understand... In this modification, because you are setting constants using the `people.get()` method, you can simply insert the constant `memberships` in the `people.updateContact()` method and it will automatically populate the existing labels?

Comment: @Corinne Jacobo `memberships` of `const { etag, memberships } = People.People.get(person, { personFields: "memberships" });` is the current memberships. In this answer, I include both the current memberships and your expected membership. If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you! This answered my question completely. Your English is clear enough for me to understand, don't worry about it. ありがとうございました！(Thank you again!)